# Appending string to dictionary values using jinja template

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, jinja2

I have the following code for accessing the values in dictionary using jinja template

```
names={'ant':['abc',2456789,28-02-1991]}
{% for key,value in names.items %}
            {% for val in value %}
              <p class="lead">{{ val }} </p>
            {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For every value,it is printed I want to append a string.My values are "abc","2456789","28-02-1991".I want the following output:

```
Name:abc
Id:2456789
Date: 28-02-1991
```

How could I do it using jinja template?

Comment: What is `val`? A list?

Comment: can you provide an example of 'name.items'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this with your current data structure.

```
{% for key, value in names.items %}
    <p class="lead">Name: {{ value.0 }}</p>
    <p class="lead">Id: {{ value.1 }}</p>
    <p class="lead">Date: {{ value.2 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But it would be more readable if change your data structure into this:

```
my_dict = {
    'ant': {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'abc',
        'date' : datetime.now()
    }
}
```

then your template would look like this:

```
{% for key, person in my_dict.items %}
    <p class="lead">Id: {{ person.id }} </p>
    <p class="lead">Name: {{ person.name }} </p>
    <p class="lead">Date: {{ person.date }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually my value is a list.So I have to loop again.

Answer (score 2):

In [*Jinja-2*](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) you can *subscript* in the variables:

```
{% for key,vals in names.items %}
    <p class="lead">Name: {{ vals[0] }}</br>
    Id: {{ vals[1] }}</br>
    Date: {{ vals[2] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The indexing doesnt work for me because I am using Django(I think this could be a reason). But I used forloop counter and it works

Comment: @SriTest: but you tag it with jinja?